# Number of days between 2 dates for each row,then Add All of them for the whole database

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
models.py
class Orders(models.Model):
  orderid = models.IntegerField(db_column='orderID', primary_key=True)  
  pickupdate = models.DateField(db_column='pickupDate', blank=True, null=True)  
  returndate = models.DateField(db_column='returnDate', blank=True, null=True)
```

I would like to substract the returndate with pickupdate (returndate - pickupdate) for each rows, and then add them together for the whole table

I have tried the code below, but it produced large decimal numbers.

```
Orders.objects.aggregate(days=Sum( F('returndate') - F('pickupdate') )
```

I also have tried the code below,but it produced error

```
Orders.objects.aggregate(days=Sum( 'returndate' - 'pickupdate' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind duplicative days in your count?  If not, you could use a range to get the total number of days between the `pickupdate` and the `returndate` for each row ...

```
days = 0
for rec in Orders.objects.all():
    for n in range(int((rec.returndate - rec.pickupdate).days)+1):
        days += 1
```

`+1` or not depending on whether you want inclusive counts (include start/end day) or exclusive counts (do not include end day).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Orders.objects.annotate(diff=F('returndate') - F('pickupdate')).aggregate(days=Sum('diff'))
```